# Create XPath for button with text

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image]

I tried with following but no luck.

```
//button[contains(text(),'Upload')]
```

Comment: Maybe the "Upload" text() property, is from the span.

Comment: Share your code and the exception log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath `//button[contains(text(),'Upload')]` will match a button whose *first* child text node contains "Upload".

It's not clear from your screenshot, but there may be an all-whitespace text node before the `<span>`, and if so, it would not contain "Upload".

Instead, try:

```
//button[contains(., 'Upload')]
```